# Incrementing constant variable

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define number 0

main()
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    number++;   
  }
  printf("Number is: %d", number);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: More specifically, what is your question? What is the problem you have with the code you show? What is the output you expect? What is the output you get? And perhaps you should take some more time with tutorials, books or classes?

Comment: and what does *"incrementing a constant variable"* even mean? What do you want to achieve? Constant variables are (as the name suggests, per definition) *constant*, and shouldn't and cannot be modified

Answer (score 1):

No, 0 is substitued for `number` by the *preprocessor* before the *compiler* gets to work.

The compiler issues a diagnostic when it sees `0++;`